# Why is `Stream.collect` type-safe and `Stream.toArray(IntFunction<A[]>)` is not?

Tags: java, types, java-8, java-stream

Consider the following code fragment

```
String strings[] = {"test"};
final List<String> collect = java.util.Arrays.stream(strings).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList());
final Double[] array = java.util.Arrays.stream(strings).toArray(Double[]::new);
```

Why can Java guarantee the correct type in the collect-case (changing the generic type of collect to e.g. Double leads to a compile time error), but not in the array case (compiles fine, despite `apply(int)` of `Double[]::new` gives a `Double[]`, not an `Object[]`, but throws `ArrayStoreException` if used incorrectly as above)?

What would be the best way to generate a compile time error in case I change the type of the stream without changing the given `IntFunction` in the `toArray` call?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The signature of the method `Stream::toArray` looks as follows. Please note that the type parameters `T` and `A` are completely unrelated.

```
public interface Stream<T> {
    <A> A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator);
}
```

In the source of [ReferencePipeline.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/82c35c2546a4/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#l428), you can find the following comment:

> Since `A` has no relation to `U` (not possible to declare that `A` is an upper bound of `U`)
>   there will be no static type checking.
>   Therefore use a raw type and assume `A == U` rather than propagating the separation of `A` and `U`
>   throughout the code-base.
>   The runtime type of `U` is never checked for equality with the component type of the runtime type of `A[]`.
>   Runtime checking will be performed when an element is stored in `A[]`, thus if `A` is not a
>   super type of `U` an `ArrayStoreException` will be thrown.

Comment: Is this one of the cases where `A super T` would help? If so, then it is quite interesting that they haven't fixed it for this as it seems like a "must" to me if it's in such an API.

Comment: Well, I am looking for the reason that they are completely unrelated, as you pointed out. Putting an `<A super T>` would seem easy enough. Thus I would expect some problem entailed in the implementations of the Stream interface or something like that.

Comment: @muued Please note that `<A super T>` is *syntactically* not possible in type declarations. You can only have `? super T` as a type, but you can not capture the `?`. This is as opposed to `X extends T` that can capture `? extends T`. It was omitted from Java at the time generics were created because it was deemed *not useful enough*.

Comment: @skiwi ah, that perfectly explains it, thanks. So the missing super you mentioned and the fact, that one cannot distinguish methods by generic types preventing them from adding a `T[] toArray(IntFunction<T[]> generator);` leads to the misery we have now

Comment: @skiwi The problem is not unique to the streams API. [`Collection.toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T[])) is an equally valid use case, so if that wasn't compelling enough to support `super`, no reason why this would be.